# Going into Mobile version using Selenium with Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to change an already opened desktop tab page into the mobile version using the inspect mode (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>) and (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>)

All the version of the codes I've tried don't seem to work. They don't put out errors but don't do anything either.

[image]

I'm working with this so far, and the inspect mode don't show up.

I also don't want to use `chromeOptions()` since it opens into the mobile version at start.

Any idea on where I messed up? or is this not supposed to work

Comment: What error do you see on the console?

Comment: There is no error in the console

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts to control the user interface don't work with selenium, for example you cannot open a new tab with `CTRL+T`. However you can use `pyautogui`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]) # hide top bar
options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs") # open devtools

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path), options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://ecosia.org')

import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','shift','m') # toggle device toolbar
```

The only problem with pyautogui is that works only on the active window, so you have to keep the browser on top.

You can also try this one

```
set_device_metrics_override = dict({
              "width": 375,
              "height": 812,
              "deviceScaleFactor": 50,
              "mobile": True
          })
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride', set_device_metrics_override)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: pyautogui don't seem to work for me, the mobile version don't display. The browser did open with devtools activated though.